# Primefaces menubar's submenu & elements width

Tags: jquery, css, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a primefaces menubar on top of my page and I tried to increase the submenus width to fit the menu-items text but it's not working.

This is a screenshot of my menu :

[image: Menu Childs]

how can I increase the submenu width to fix the text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css rule. Change width to whatever you require.

```
ul.ui-widget-content.ui-menu-list.ui-menu-child {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Note this will stuff up other styles e.g

```
.ui-menubar .ui-menu-child .ui-menuitem-link {
    width: 92%;
 }
```

You may need to change this too.